# Loading a XML file from a shared Project

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, project, shared

I am using Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin

### Project Structure

```
Shared (Shared Project name)
    GameData
        Levels
            Level1
                Level1Data.xml
                Level1DataXML.cs
        ReadMe.txt

    MainMenuSystem
        LevelSelectionConfiguration.cs
```

### Level1DataXML.cs:

```
using System;
using Foundation;

namespace Mind2MindV1.GameData.Levels.Level1
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    public class Level1DataXML
    {
        public string Title;
        public string Description;
        public string LevelPuzzlesData;
    }
}
```

### Level1Data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Level1DataXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Title>Level 1</Title>
    <Description>Level 1 Puzzles Data</Description>
    <LevelPuzzlesData>GameData/Level1/Lvl1Puzzles/Level1PuzzlesData.xml</LevelPuzzlesData>
</Level1DataXML>
```

My Conde in "LevelSelectionConfiguration.cs"

### for loading the xml file:

```
 var assembly = typeof(Level1DataXML).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; 
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GameData.Levels.Level1.Level1Data.xml"); 
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)) { 
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Level1DataXML)); 
                xmlData = (Level1DataXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
            }
```

assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GameData.Levels.Level1.Level1Data.xml");  is returning "null"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there are several things that could cause this, including project settings.  I'd say take a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c) it might help.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m having the same issue with my shared project.